# PHP return output based on zero, empty or value

Tags: php, wordpress, key-value, string

I have a simple requirement which is proving difficult. I'm using Wordpress to store a meta value 'session_capacity', this can have the following possible values

- 0
- integer e.g. 99
- nothing, left blank

The problem is when the value stored is zero, I can't figure out what setup to use to get echo a different statement based on whether it's zero or empty.

This is my desired output...

if (zero)
  // do something
elseif (integer e.g. 99)
  // do something
elseif (blank)
  // do something

Actual function...

```
function get_session_capacity($post_id){
    // Get the total capacity of this session
    $session_capacity = get_post_meta($post_id, 'session_capacity', true);
    // Meta value was sometimes stored as a string so converting to integer
    $session_capacity = intval($session_capacity);

    if($session_capacity === 0) 
        return 'You cannot book this session';
    elseif(empty($session_capacity))
        return default_session_capacity();
    else
        return $session_capacity;
}
```

Comment: Empty is for arrays or strings.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `empty()` use [is_null()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php)

It should look like this:

```
function get_session_capacity($post_id){
    $session_capacity = get_post_meta($post_id, 'session_capacity', true);

    if(is_null($session_capacity))
         return default_session_capacity();
    elseif($session_capacity == 0) 
         return 'You cannot book this session';
    else
        return intval($session_capacity);
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to  insanebits for the tips in the comment section. :)

Comment: It won't work because intval(null) returns integer(0) so is_null will return false

Comment: I believe this wont work either :P try var_dump('' == 0) and it should return true so empty would be taken as zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `$session_capacity` is set or not, and set is accordingly

```
$session_capacity = isset($session_capacity)? intVal($session_capacity) : null;
```

Or even better

```
$session_capacity = (isset($session_capacity) && !empty($session_capacity))? intVal($session_capacity) : null;
```

The latter works even when variable is set to empty string. It doesn't give `0` when `$session_capacity` is not set (blank)

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = array(null, 0, 99);

$i = 1;
foreach ($values as $value) {
  if ($value === null) {
    echo $i . ': equals null!<br />';
  }
  if ($value === 0) {
    echo $i . ': equals the integer 0!<br />';
  }
  if (is_integer($value)) {
    echo $i . ': contains any integer!<br />';
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Output:

```
1: equals null!
2: equals the integer 0!
2: contains any integer!
3: contains any integer!
```